# Load another website content in my web page using JS

Tags: javascript, html, load

I have my page, let's call it a.html and I would like to show in this page (for example in a paragraph) the paragraph of another website (let's say www.abc.com/b.html).
Is this possible using javascript? I don't want to load all the b page, but just a little part that has a particular id

Comment: Not possible, you are only allowed to do JSONP. Cross document messaging feature of HTML5 might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is no for security reason, you've to proxy the external page through a server side service.

As far as I know there are some recent way to do it, but I'm not sure they would work for any external site neither for any browser.

From the comment of Gurpreet Singh you can read : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: arg.. thank you.. it's a shame I have to deal with security issues whil I just want to show some plain text taken from another site

Comment: @endamaco Do you think it would be OK if any website could order your computer to talk to any other website?

Comment: @endamaco maybe you could look at iframes (you could create them with JS), that's not clean but that work !

Answer (score 0):

You can try with iframe and some css tricks. Just add the iframe to the div where you want to show the other page content.